# how to push object except duplicate object in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to add an object to an array.
But I want to remove duplicate objects.

here is mongoDB JSON

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61ef7e003307047c13329d"),
    "subject" : "Grammar",
    "deletedYn" : false,
    "answerList" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e61ef8c003307047c1332a4"),
            "sentence" : "hi gui, nice to meet you",
            "answer" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61f15cd863e104a8f66770"),
                    "word" : "nice",
                    "index" : 3
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e61ef8c003307047c1332a5"),
            "sentence" : "how to make a project.",
            "answer" : []
        }
    ],
    "passageId" : "123",
}
```

So I want to push answer in answerList.
Below is the code I created, but it contains duplicate objects.

```
        const update = await PassageGrammar.updateOne(
          {
            _id: passageGrammarId,
            answerList: { $elemMatch: { _id: sentenceId } },
          },
          {
            $addToSet: {
              'answerList.$.answer': {
                word: answerList.word,
                index: answerList.index,
              },
            },
          },
        );
```

but It is not working (it has duplicate set) like that:

```
            "answer" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61f15cd863e104a8f66770"),
                    "word" : "nice",
                    "index" : 3
                },
               {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5e61f15cd863e104a8f66770"),
                    "word" : "nice",
                    "index" : 3
                }
            ]
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating a unique index each time and droping the duplicates if they exist

```
    const update = await PassageGrammar.updateOne(
          {
            _id: passageGrammarId,
            answerList: { $elemMatch: { _id: sentenceId } },
          },
          {
            $addToSet: {
              'answerList.$.answer': {
                word: answerList.word,
                index: answerList.index,
              },
            },
          },
          { unique:true, dropDups:true } 
        );
```